# Joining two dataframes where a date in one falls into an interval in another. R

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, lubridate

I am trying to fill one dataframe with values from another based on whether a date from the first fits into an interval in the second.

Right now, I am doing this with a nested for loop, but needless to say, this method is painfully slow.

Here is some sample data and my nested for loop:

```
library(lubridate)

periods <- structure(list(week = structure(c(16475, 16489, 16531, 16545,16559, 16573, 16587, 16615, 16629, 16643, 16657, 16671, 16685, 
16699, 16727, 16741, 16755, 16769, 16783, 16797, 16811, 16825
), class = "Date"), poll = c(6.5, 4, 12, 11.5, 13, 9.5, 7, 8, 
4.5, 4.5, 7.5, 4.8, 6.33333333333333, 7.5, 11.125, 13, 12, 12.8571428571429, 
10.5, 13, 11, 4)), .Names = c("week", "poll"), row.names = 82:103, class = "data.frame")

periods$week <- as.interval(ymd(period$week), ymd(period$week + weeks(2)))


weeks <- structure(list(week = structure(c(16720, 16622, 16776, 16720, 
        16734, 16741), class = "Date"), poll = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        13)), .Names = c("week", "poll"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


for (i in seq_along(weeks$week)){
          x <- weeks$week[i]
          for (j in seq_along(periods$int)){
            if (is.na(x)==T){next}
            else if (x %within% periods$int[j]==T){weeks$poll <- periods[j,2]}
            else {next}  
          }
        }
```

I'm assuming there's an apply function that will speed this up, but I can't seem to make it work... Thanks much for all the help!

Comment: Look at package data.table and its `foverlaps` function.

Comment: Are u sure this code works properly? The periods$int[j] is class numeric in the if else clause and %within% does not work.

Comment: It looks like using dput to output data created with the lubridate package doesn't work. I will edit the post to make the reproducible data clearer

Comment: @Roland I've been having trouble with foverlaps, but I think it might be the solution. Do you have any suggestions on how to start?

Comment: @StanoO `?foverlaps` and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/talks/EARL2014_OverlapRangeJoin_Arun.pdf

Comment: @Stano Maybe it's just that your left ranges are single dates so it's kind of a  simple special case for foroverlaps which does overlapping ranges (so pass two columns to it, both equal).  You may want to look at `roll='nearest'` too.  Just guessing.

Comment: That presentation looks promising @MattDowle. I'll look through it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improvised a solution that worked in my case, so I'll post it here in case anyone else finds themselves in a similar bind.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

periods <- structure(list(week = structure(c(16475, 16489, 16531, 16545,16559, 16573, 16587, 16615, 16629, 16643, 16657, 16671, 16685, 
16699, 16727, 16741, 16755, 16769, 16783, 16797, 16811, 16825
), class = "Date"), poll = c(6.5, 4, 12, 11.5, 13, 9.5, 7, 8, 
4.5, 4.5, 7.5, 4.8, 6.33333333333333, 7.5, 11.125, 13, 12, 12.8571428571429, 
10.5, 13, 11, 4)), .Names = c("week", "poll"), row.names = 82:103, class = "data.frame")

periods$week2 <- ymd(periods$week + weeks(2))

structure(list(week = structure(c(16720, 16622, 16776, 16720, 
16734, 16741), class = "Date"), poll = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("week", "poll"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

week$week2 <- week$week

setDT(periods)
setDT(weeks)
setkey(periods, week, week2)
setkey(weeks, week, week2)

merged = foverlaps(periods, weeks, by.x=c("week", "week2"))
```

It's not pretty, but it works for my case.